# How to validate time string in hh:mm using preg match?

Tags: php, regex, string, time, preg-match

Below are the following possiblities. Time is for 12 hours

```
 Inputs          Output should as

"05:30"           True
"asasds"          FALSE
"05:30:sads"      FALSE
"ADAS:05:40"      FALSE
"04:30:40"        FALSE
```

Below is the code that I wrote,

```
 $value = "05:30" ;
if(!preg_match("/(1[012]|0[0-9]):([0-5][0-9])/", $value)){
    echo "failed"; exit;
}
echo "passed"; exit;
```

But it prints as passed if I give the $value = "05:30:asdsa". However I need the output to be "*failed*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [anchors](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php) to match the start and the end, e.g.

```
!preg_match("/^(1[012]|0[0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$/", $value)
            //^ See here                   ^
```

Answer (score 0):

I just coded it for myself some minutes ago. It is basically controlling that is between 00:00 and 23:59

**edit**

```
preg_match("/(0?\d|1\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d/", $line, $matches_time);
```

Comment: He doesn't want to  match time greater than `12:59`

Comment: true! sorry! my script was different of course hehe

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that 25:30 is not valid. 24:00 is not valid but 00:00 is valid.
this code can make it perfect:

```
$string='00:34';  
$pattern='%^([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$%';

if(preg_match($pattern,$string))
    echo '<b>'.$string.'</b> is a valid time in 24 hours format';
```

If you want to check only 12 hours format, you can use this one:

```
$string='09:24';  
$pattern='%^([0][0-9])|([1][0-2]):[0-5][0-9]$%';

if(preg_match($pattern,$string))
    echo '<b>'.$string.'</b> is a valid time in 12 hours format';
```